# Fourier transform of $f(x)=-2e^{-x}+3e^{-2x}$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

I am trying to find FT of the function $$f(x)=-2e^{-x}+3e^{-2x}$$.
we have
$$F(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(-2 e^{-x}+3 e^{-2 x}\right) e^{-i \omega x} d x$$
$\implies$
$$F(w)=-2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(1+i \omega) x} d x+3 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(2+i \omega) x} d x$$
But after integration, the lower limits are bothering me?

Comment: Are you sure the exponentials are not defined for $x\ge 0$ only?

Comment: @Paul [That would be nice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform).

Comment: @J.G. I would give my students a straightforward function like $e^{-x}u(x)$, which is why I ask.

Comment: @Paul [Ah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), thanks for clarifying.

Comment: ok fine i understood that there should be $u(x)$ multiplied with the function.Then only integral converges.

Comment: The integral does not exist. In fact that function does not _have_ a Fourier transform, as far as I can see; it's certainly not a tempered distribution.